# Equal sizing for jQueryUI buttons despite their varying content length

Tags: html, jquery-ui, css, button

I was trying to use [`Button` from `jQueryUI`](http://jqueryui.com/button/#radio) and wonder how to make buttons appear of equal size (preferably centered on the screen). The size of a button seem to grow/shrink based on the text. I would like to know how to fix the size of all the buttons to (say) the button with the longest text in it.

I have [my code on github](https://github.com/programmertote/demo) if anyone would like to download and try it out (sorry that I couldn't share it on jsfiddle because it's too difficult to get it to work with multiple files/dependencies on it; I tried). Also if you'd like to take a quick look, it is also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645976/equal-sizing-for-jqueryui-buttons-despite-their-varying-content-length) as well.

My goal is to center those buttons and have them all equal size.

I'm a beginner learning javascript, CSS, HTML and web development in general. If anyone could help me explain/figure out how to achieve that, I'd greatly appreciate the help. Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you put the code on a JSfiddle please, instead of your live site. You'll probably get help faster.

Comment: Hi @Antoine I was trying to share it on jsfiddle, but couldn't get it to work. But I just figured out how to :) Please check it out and give me suggestions. I am having trouble putting the buttons in the center (inside `#response` without limiting its width. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to give provide the link: http://jsfiddle.net/Akedf/1/
Could you please take a look at my comment to answer below and see if you can help? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the max width from the button with the longest text using this code:

```
var maxWidth = Math.max.apply(null, $(".ui-button").map(function () {
    return $(this).outerWidth(true);
}).get());
```

Note I'm using the selector `$(".ui-button")` since all `jQuery UI` buttons have this CSS class. Then apply `maxWidth` to all buttons:

```
$(".ui-button").css({"width" : maxWidth});
```

Here's a working JS Bin demo: http://jsbin.com/ihuquq/1/edit

Comment: Thank you @LenielMacaferi. Your solution works. :) I am also wondering how I might go about centralizing these buttons/choices in the browser window inside `#response`. Since I want the number of buttons to vary (up to 8 buttons), it would be the best if I don't have to limit the width of the `#response`. For now, the only way I know to center a div (without disrupting other elements on the page) is to do `margin-left/right: auto`, but that requires me to set the width of a div. Is there other way around to dynamically determine a div's size and center it in the browser window? Thank you!

Comment: I think that what you want is simply `text-align:center` CSS rule for the response `div` like this: http://jsbin.com/ihuquq/4. Doing like that there's no need to set the `div`'s width.

Comment: Thank you @LenielMacaferi again for the follow up answer. Yes, that's exactly what I wanted. :) Also if you don't mind answering more, what is the best way to control/align the height of those buttons? As you see in the jsbin example you provided, the "Disagree Strongly" button is higher than others. Is there a way to make sure all of them are of equal height and width? Thank you.

Comment: Oh... I see. The problem was that the code was using `.outerWidth(true)`. Just change it to `.outerWidth(false)`. For more info on this, look here: http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/. The updated JS Bin is here: http://jsbin.com/ihuquq/6

Comment: Thank you, @LenielMacaferi! That is really awesome. :) You also provided the source of `outerWidth`. I was wondering how you came up with that. The use of `map` is pretty cool, too. Surely, I'm learning useful stuff.

Also, do you think laying this many buttons side by side is a good idea (in terms of visual) or is it better stacking them on top of one another? What css-property would do the trick of stacking them up vertically (with width aligned)? Sorry if it seems like I'm making you do the work.I wanted to see how experienced programmer would go about doing it.I can do it but it'll be ugly

Comment: Stacked or not is a matter of preference and how many buttons you're going to have. Anyways, you can have them stacked this way: http://jsbin.com/ihuquq/8

Comment: Thank you so much @LenielMacaferi! I wonder how you figure these out. Is that mostly due to experience with CSS? I am very confused by those obscure CSS options. Is there a good book/resource you'd recommend to get the ground covered (tried W3School, but isn't only good as reference)? Thanks again. :)

Comment: This comes with time so I'd say this is experience. :) From basic `CSS` constructs you go learning each day new ones that allow you to do great things. Most of the time I keep trying different options till I get the desired result. I started learning `HTML` and `CSS` in 2000 so it's a lot of time since then. The best resource is the internet. When I have a doubt I just type in Google and I get here at StackOverflow where I find amazing answers and where I learn a lot of things too. When I want to see a reference I generally go to `W3School`. They cover every piece of HTML and CSS... PRACTICE!

Comment: You're very kind and helpful.Thanks a lot, @LenielMacaferi!I guess since I just started learning CSS/HTML stuff, I should wait for like another 15yrs until I know what I'm doing. :) I'll definitely follow what you just told me--to read and learn every day bit by bit.

On a side note, I'm trying to align the <label> and <span> elements here at http://jsfiddle.net/Mhekk/ with the <textarea>'s top left and bottom right corners respectively. Is there a way to do it without having to resort to jQuery to calculate position of <textarea>?I promise this is the last question I bug you and thanks a lot!